# Angular, vistas, porque no veo los datos del libro, me falta codigo?

Tags: android, json, vistas, http-get

se que he venido formulando algunas preguntas con respecto a Angular, tengo una situación con mi código que tratare de explicar lo mejor que pueda, ya que necesito resolver esto pronto.
Tengo estos dos links:
link para autor:

```
https://the-books--goncalomatos2.repl.co/search?author=tolkien
```

y el link para un libro de ese autor, (este es de un libro con id= OL26757374M)

```
https://the-books--goncalomatos2.repl.co/books?id=OL26757374M
```

Yo consigo acceder a la lista de libros del autor como muestro a continuación:

[image: lista de libros con su link]

al hacer click en algun link de libros deberia traerme: titulo, autor, foto de la cubierta y un resumen del libro, que según veo es información que esta compartida entre el primer y segundo link, por ejemplo se que puedo ver el titulo del libro y el autor desde el primer link, y se que el segundo link tiene la cubierta y el resumen. La cosa es que al hacer click solo me trae el titulo y creo tener todo en orden porque no muestra error alguno en consola o en compilador, anexo imagen:

[image: libro después de hacer click en el primer libro]

ahora coloco mi codigo:

Api service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, forkJoin, merge } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { BooksDictionary, Book, DocsServer, Resume } from './types';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ApiService {
  //cacheamos los Books
  booksCache: BooksDictionary;

  constructor( private http: HttpClient) { }

  //funcion para formatear los datos
 // private _extractId(urn) {
 //   return urn.substring(urn.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
 // }

  private _adaptBookFromServe( data:any ): Book {
    return {
      id: data.id,
      title: data.title,
      author: data.author_name[0],

    }
  }

  private _adaptResumeFromServe( data:any ): Resume {
    return {
      id: data.id,
      name: data.title,
      author: data.author_name,
      resume: data.resume,
      cover: data.cover

    }
  }

  private _adaptBooksFromServe(data: DocsServer): Book[] {
    return data.docs.map<Book>(serverBook => this._adaptBookFromServe(serverBook));
  }

  getBooks(): Observable<BooksDictionary> {
    if ((this.booksCache)) {
      return of(this.booksCache);
    }

    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/search?author=tolkien').pipe(map<any, BooksDictionary>(data => {
        const booksList = this._adaptBooksFromServe(data);
        this.booksCache = Object.fromEntries(
          booksList.map(book => [book.id, book])

        );

        return this.booksCache;
      })
    );
  }

  getBook(id: string): Observable<Book> {
    if (this.booksCache[id]) {
      return of(this.booksCache[id]);
    }

    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/books?bibkeys=OLID:${id}&format=json&jscmd=details`).pipe(
      map<any, Book>(book => this._adaptBookFromServe(book))
    );
  }
}
```

Componentes:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from './../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-book-select',
  templateUrl: './book-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./book-select.component.css']
})
export class BookSelectComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string;

  constructor(
    private api:  ApiService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      const id= params.get('id');

      this.api.getBook(id).subscribe(book => {
        this.title = book.title;

      })
    })
  }
}
```

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { ApiService } from './../api.service';
import { Link } from './../link-list/link-list.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-book-list',
  templateUrl: './book-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./book-list.component.css']
})
export class BookListComponent implements OnInit {
  bookLinks: Link[];
  bookSubscription$: Subscription;

  constructor( private api: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('books list was build');
    this.bookSubscription$ = this.api.getBooks().subscribe((book) => {
      const bookList = Object.values(book);
      console.log(bookList)

      this.bookLinks = bookList.map<Link>(book => {
        return {
          title: book.title,
          url: `/books/${book.id}`
        };
      });
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log('books-List was destroyed');
    this.bookSubscription$.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Agradecido de antemano por tomarse el tiempo para leer y ayudar

**EDICION**

componentes html:

```
    app.component.html
    <div>
      <nav>
    <h1>Lista de Libros</h1>
      </nav>

    <app-book-select></app-book-select>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

```
book-select.component
{{title}}
{{Author}}
{{Description}}
```

```
book-list.component
 <app-link-list [linkList]="bookLinks"></app-link-list>
```

y cambie en el book-select.component.ts:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      const id= params.get('id');

      this.api.getBook(id).subscribe(book => {
        this.title = book.title;
        this.author = book.author;
        this.description = book.description;

      })
    })

  }
```

```
Interfaces
interface BooksDictionary{ 
    [id: string]: Book;

}

interface Book {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    author: string[];
    description: string;
    cover:string

}

interface Docs {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

interface DocsServer {
    docs: any[];
}

interface Resume {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    author: string;
    resume: string;
    cover: string
}


//las exporto para poder usarlas en mis componentes o mi apiService
export { BooksDictionary, Book, Docs, DocsServer, Resume }
```

pero estoy convencido de que es esta linea de codigo que no esta a leerse porque no llega alli ninguna peticion:

```
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/books?id=${id}`).pipe(
      map<any, Book>(book => this._adaptBookFromServe(book)),
    );
  }
```

si ven y comparan este segmento de codigo con el que envie anteriormente solo cambie esto `books?id=${id}`, ya que segun veo en los link dados, es la manera correcta en que se lee los detalles del libro:

[image: prueba de los datos que trae el link de detalle libro]

la cosa es segun mi api-service como salto del link autor al link detalles libro para que me de los datos que necesito?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from './../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-book-select',
  templateUrl: './book-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./book-select.component.css']
})
export class BookSelectComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string;
  description : string,

  constructor(
    private api:  ApiService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      const id= params.get('id');

      this.api.getBook(id).subscribe(book => {
        this.title = book.title;
        this.description = book.description

      })
    })
  }
}
```

si te fijas en tu componente solo tienes el `this.title` y `title` declarado, te hace falta colocar los demas campos, prueba agregando `description` ahi lo he colocado.

Comment: Buenas José, he probado pero solo sigue apareciendo el title, no se si es el html, pero pruebo con {{title}} y aparece lo quito y pues no aparece, lo mismo intento con autor y descripcion pero no aparecen.... este es el codigo de la vista de book-select.component: {{title}}
{{Author}}

Comment: Muestra el html completo, edita la pregunta por favor para tener más claro

Comment: listo la edicion tienen los html y las interfaces ademas de algunas muestras de codigo cambiado